# A better way to introspect a capture

Tags: raku, introspection

I want to test the type of the first object in a signature. The following shows some ways I have found that work. But why does a smart match on a Type (2nd of the 3 tests below) not work?
Is there a better way than stringifying and testing for the string equivalent of the Type?
(Below is the use case I am working on)

```
raku -e "sub a( |c ) { say so |c[0].WHAT.raku ~~ /'Rat'/, so |c[0].WHAT ~~ Rat, so |c[0].^name ~~ /'Rat'/ };a(3/2);a(2)"
TrueFalseTrue
FalseFalseFalse
# OUTPUT:
#TrueFalseTrue
#FalseFalseFalse
```

I am writing a `proto sub handle`, and most of the subs have similar signatures, eg. `multi sub handle( Pod $node, MyObj $p, Int $level --> Str)`

So most of the multi subs do different things depending on what is in $node. However, how to handle cases when the `handle` is called with `Nil` or a plain string. I am thinking about something like

```
proto handle(|c) {
    if |c[0].^name ~~ /'Str'/ { # code for string }
    else { {*} }
}
```

Comment: `proto foo(| [$first, |]) { say $first.perl; {*}; }`, or maybe more clearly without the anonymous captures as `proto foo(|all [$first, |rest]) { say $first.perl; {*}; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A better way to introspect ...

In general, a better way to do *anything* in any programming language is to *not* introspect if you can avoid it.

In general, in Raku, you *can* avoid manual introspection. See the section **Introspection** toward the end of this answer for further discussion.

> ... a capture

The best tool for getting the functionality that introspection of a capture provides is to use a signature. That's their main purpose in life.

> I want to test the type of the first object in a signature

Use signatures:

```
proto handle(|) {*}
multi handle( Pod $node )   { ... }
multi handle( Str $string ) { ... }
multi handle( Nil )         { ... }
```

> The following shows some ways I have found that work.

While they do what you want, they are essentially ignoring all of Raku's signature features. They reduce the signature to just a binding to the capture as a single structure; and then use manual introspection of that capture in the routine's body.

There's almost always a simpler and better way to do such things using signatures.

> why does [`|c[0].WHAT ~~ Rat`, with `c[0] == 3/2`] not work?

I'll simplify first, then end up with what your code is doing:

```
say    3/2        ~~ Rat;  # True
say   (3/2)       ~~ Rat;  # True
say   (3/2).WHAT  ~~ Rat;  # True
say |((3/2).WHAT  ~~ Rat); # True
say (|(3/2).WHAT) ~~ Rat;  # False
say  |(3/2).WHAT  ~~ Rat;  # False
```

The last case is because `|` has a higher [precedence](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Operator_precedence) than `~~`.

> Is there a better way than stringifying and testing for the string equivalent of the Type?

OMG yes.

Use the types, Luke.

(And in your use case, do so using signatures.)

## Introspection

Compared to code that manually introspects incoming data in the body of a routine, appropriate use of signatures will typically:

- Read better;
- Generate better low-level code;
- Be partially or fully evaluated during the *compile* phase.

If a language and its compiler have addressed a use case by providing a particular feature, such as signatures, then using that feature instead of introspection will generally lead to the above three benefits.

Languages/compilers can be broken into four categories, namely those that:

1. Do not do or allow any introspection;
2. Allow the *compiler* to introspect, but not *devs*;
3. Allow both the compiler and devs to introspect, but aim to make it a last resort, at least for devs;
4. Enable and encourage devs to introspect.

Raku(do) are in the third category. In the context of this SO, signatures are the primary feature that all but eliminates any need for a dev to manually introspect.

Comment: I guess you mean explicit introspection; signatures do implicit introspection. But do you care to explain why introspection is not good? Maybe too much power in the wrong hands when implicit ways of checking type are much better?

Comment: Thanks for your spot on comment; I've updated my answer. Note that, while I agree with you, in some sense it's about the opposite of what you wrote regarding explicit/implicit. As far as Rakudo is concerned, signatures *explicitly* do what signatures do, whereas user code that does introspection is only *implicitly* doing what signatures do. Also, it's arguable whether signatures always do "introspection". A (weak) example of both this implicit/explicit distinction, and "introspection" being debatable, is that Rakudo can reject some programs during compilation (optimization) due to signatures.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply smartmatch to a type:

```
raku -e "sub a( *@c ) { say @c[0] ~~ Rat };a(3/2);a(2)" 
True
False
```

Also I am using here a [slurpy](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-slurpy_argument) and not a capture, which is another alternative. Any way, with a single argument you're probably better off using [type captures](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-Type_capture)

```
raku -e "sub a( ::T $ ) { say ::T ~~ Rat };a(3/2);a(2)" 
True
False
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pull stuff out of a Capture in the signature.

```raku
# ( |C ( ::Type $a, +@b ) )
proto handle( | ( ::Type, +@ ) ) {
    if Type ~~ Str {
        …
    } else {
        {*}
    }
}
```

Basically a `::Foo` before a parameter (or instead of it) is similar to `.WHAT` on that parameter.

It also becomes usable as a type descriptor.

```raku
sub foo ( ::Type $a ) {
    my Type $b = $a;
}
```

---

It is an incredibly bad idea to compare types based on their name.

```raku
my $a = anon class Foo { has $.a }
my $b = anon class Foo { has $.b }

say $a.WHAT =:= $b.WHAT; # False

say $a.^name eq $b.^name; # True
```

As far as Raku is concerned it is entirely a coincidence that two types happen to have the same name.
If you do use the names, your code will be confused about the reality of the situation.

Comment: The extra information here is very interesting. Is it in the Docs? If not, maybe it could be added